# What is the difference between underscore _.each and forEach?

Tags: javascript, foreach, underscore.js, each

I study Backbone n underscore.
somebody help me.
 
I don't know that model is undefined of _.each().

```
 var todos = new Backbone.Collection();

    todos.add([
        { title: 'go to Belgium.', completed: false },
        { title: 'go to China.', completed: false },
        { title: 'go to Austria.', completed: true }
    ]);

    // iterate over models in the collection 
    todos.forEach(function(model){
        console.log(model.get('title'));
    });
    // Above logs:
    // go to Belgium.
    // go to China.
    // go to Austria.
```

*Why model is undefined???*

```
    /*underscoreJS  model is undefined...*/
    _.each(todos, function (model) {
        console.log(model.get('title'));
    });
```

Comment: Backbone has proxy of `_.each` method which you have to use in your case: `todos.each(function(todo) {...})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For underscore you need to do like this:

```
 _.each(todos.models, function(model) {
   console.log(model.get('title'));
 });
```

Reason when you do

```
 var todos = new Backbone.Collection();

 todos.add([{
   title: 'go to Belgium.',
   completed: false
 }, {
   title: 'go to China.',
   completed: false
 }, {
   title: 'go to Austria.',
   completed: true
 }]);
```

Backbone returns a proxy object which hold the model array in `todos.models`

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/7aby5ftx/)